# Why CSS doesn't match with Angular 6 selector component?

Tags: html, css, angular

**app.html**

```
<app-chat></app-chat>
```

**chat.html**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

**chat.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**chat.css**

```
h1 {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

I need to know why the `chat.css` doesn't work in my browser. When I used CSS directly without chat component it works (like below).

**app.html**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

**app.css**

```
h1 {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

So what is the solution?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: Hey, please also post the `chat.component.ts`

Comment: Could you share with us a working example of your problem in a fiddle/snippet?
Because as you said the css inside your "chat.css" file should working if load corectly on your component, without necessarly put the css code in an outer ".css" file.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpfcrx

This is how it usually works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
::ng-deep h1{
   background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: in the chat.css ?

Comment: can you explain me the ::ng-deep functionality !

Answer (score 1):

Try `!important` in your chat.css file

```
h1{
   background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

or

Use the powerful weapon of CSS **style.css**. But, before using it you have to set the class name for **h1 tag**.

**chat.html**

```
<h1 class="exampleClassName">Helo<h1>
```

Next, in your **style.css** file

```
.exampleClassName{
     background-color: #000;
 }
```

Comment: Advising to use `!important` is a very irresponsible thing to do :P

Comment: @inconnu I Updated my answer. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

I did an example and it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u99pry